# Get Array from multiple select using isFormField stream / multipart form. Java Servlet

Tags: java, forms, servlets

Trying to get the values from a **multiple select field**. But only able to retrieve the first value?

In a normal form, have no problem iterating over the field name with a for-loop and then adding the values to an array.

But when using a **Multipart request form**, having trouble understanding how exactly it would be possible to get those same values?

For instance,

servlet:

```
      String sctype = null, sfieldname = null, sname = null;
      FileItemIterator iterator;
      FileItemStream item = null;
      InputStream stream = null;
try{

        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();
        iterator = upload.getItemIterator(request);

      while (iterator.hasNext()) { // iterate over form fields

                          item = iterator.next();
                          stream = item.openStream();
                          String fieldname = item.getFieldName();

         if (item.isFormField()) { // Problem here

                          String value = Streams.asString(stream);

                          //String[] valueArray = Streams.asString(stream) //test

                 if (fieldname.equals("title")){

                      title = value;
                  }

                 if (fieldname.equals("multipleSelect")){

                      //multipleSelect = valueArray[]; //test
                      multipleSelect = value;  // only gives one value :S 

                 } else { // gets values from uploaded files

                      sfieldname = item.getFieldName();
                      sname = item.getName();
                      sctype = item.getContentType();

                      stream.close();

                 }

      } // if form
  } // while

} ....( try catch block/finally, etc)...
```

jsp/html

```
    <form action="FormServlet" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <textarea class="form-control" name="title" placeholder="Title"></textarea>

        <select  class="form-control"  name="multipleSelect" multiple="multiple">
            <option value="ring">Ring</option>
            <option value="necklace">Necklace</option>
        </select>

       <input type="file" name="file1" size="50" multiple>

    </form>
```

Hope that was clear. Any pointers much appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple **workaround** which I have used

1. Create a hidden text field between `<form>` and `</form>` for storing the selected item values of the dropdown as a delimited string (a comma in this example). (i.e:'ring,necklace')

   ```
   <input type="hidden" id="multipleSelectValues" name="multipleSelectValues" />
   ```
2. Add client-side JavaScript/JQuery..etc so that when the selected values are changed, the text in the hidden text field would update.

   ```
   $("select[name='multipleSelect']").change(function() {
       var arr = $("select[name='multipleSelect']").val(); //automatically creates an array of selected values
       var foo = arr.join(","); //creates a comma delimited string (i.e:'ring,necklace')
       $( "#multipleSelectValues" ).val(foo); //update hidden field value
   });
   ```
3. At the servlet, the values can be parsed using string `split()` command.

   ```
   if (fieldname.equals("multipleSelect")){
       String[] valueArray = value.split(","); //split string by ,
       //do your array stuff here, for example
       for (String individualValue: valueArray ) {           
           //play with individual dropdown item here, for example
           System.out.println(individualValue);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you VeteranLK, that works perfectly! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**

The result of the parse is a List of file items, each of which implements the FileItem interface.​

e.g.

```
List items = upload.parseRequest(request);
Iterator iter = items.iterator();

while (iter.hasNext()) {
    FileItem item = (FileItem) iter.next();

    if (item.isFormField()) {
       String name = item.getFieldName();
       String value = item.getString();

    List<String> valueArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    if(name.equals("multipleSelect"))
        valueArray​.add(value);
 }
```

So all you have to do is fetch all values one by one and then convert it into required data-type (i.e. - as collect everything in a List and convert it into String[] :) )

Comment: Thanks for the info, but that doesn't really answer the question. Getting the field name for "title" isn't a problem. What is difficult is getting a multiple select field within a Multipart form.... ( so handling an Array, not a string, in the stream)

Comment: Saw your edit, tried it out, still doesn't work unfortunately.. That seems to only give the last selected value of the multiple select field, still. Thanks for the help nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

I did not find any issues with what code you provided.

The code is running fine , I think it may be an issue with the commons jar version.

Comment: Try selecting multiple options for the selection input. You'll see that you can only select 1 option. I wouldn't have asked this question if there wasn't a problem. All jars are correctly implemented.

Comment: It did not replicated on my end and I used the code that was provided above , I was able to select multiple values in select. When I selected multiple values I could see multiple values being printed and a single value when I selected a single one.

Comment: "it did not replicated on my end"

Clearly. If you used the exact same code as above, there's no way you could have possibly got multiple select options working... Perhaps you're forgetting enctype="multipart/form-data", or are doing something different. Please show your code / screenshots. I'm curious as to how you think you got it working using the same code provided above. Talk is cheap.